# Is there any good way to store records of the change in status together with number of days after status change

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table to record the current products status as follow:

| product_id | Date | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 20/10/2021 | manufacturing |
| A1 | 22/10/2021 | packaging |
| A1 | 24/10/2021 | pending to deliver |

But I want to store the number of days after status change in my database too for tracking and analysis purpose. Similar to this:

| product_id | Date | status | days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 20/10/2021 | manufacturing | 2 |
| A1 | 22/10/2021 | packaging | 2 |
| A1 | 24/10/2021 | pending to deliver | #no. of day until today's date |

I want the #no. of day until today's date to update everyday and stop until a new status is posted.

| product_id | Date | status | days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 20/10/2021 | manufacturing | 2 |
| A1 | 22/10/2021 | packaging | 2 |
| A1 | 24/10/2021 | pending to deliver | 3 |
| A1 | 27/10/2021 | delivered | null |

And when the status is 'delivered' the days is null.
I am completely new to PostgreSQL, a lot of things still yet to be discover. I not so sure whether my ways of thinking is correct or not. Or is there any good ways to keep track of the time need for products to more from one status to another.
I hope I can get some sense of solving it.

Comment: Storing the number of days would be a mistake - it's *derived* data, can always be calculated from other data on hand. By choosing to store it, you *introduce* the opportunity for it to be inconsistent.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Oh, that means I have to store only date, then only calculate the days by query is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

What you need a `SELECT` with either `LAG()` or `LEAD()` to calculate the days on demand - storing them isn't necessary and is not recommended, as you'd need to change this column every time the date columns get updated. The following example checks the status of a record and calculates the interval in days from the `date` column to the current date in case the status is `pending to deliver`. If it is not pending, it calculates the actual record to the next status change (`1 FOLLOWING`):

```
SELECT 
    *,
    CASE 
        WHEN status = 'pending to deliver' AND LEAD(dt) OVER w IS NULL 
            THEN CURRENT_DATE - LEAD(dt) OVER w
        WHEN status = 'pending to deliver' AND LEAD(dt) OVER w IS NOT NULL 
            THEN LEAD(dt) OVER w-dt
        WHEN status = 'delivered' 
            THEN NULL
        ELSE LEAD(dt) OVER w-dt
    END AS days
FROM 
    t
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY dt ASC 
             ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING);


 product_id |     dt     |       status       | days 
------------+------------+--------------------+------
 A1         | 2021-10-20 | manufacturing      |    2
 A1         | 2021-10-22 | packaging          |    2
 A1         | 2021-10-24 | pending to deliver |    3
 A1         | 2021-10-27 | delivered          |     
 A2         | 2021-10-22 | packaging          |    2
 A2         | 2021-10-24 | pending to deliver |
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c347c60b1d0df9fa6092f85d160b493f)